# Possible to host ASP.NET MVC controllers+views within a webforms project...?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, legacy, technical-debt, hybrid

We have a legacy ASP.NET webforms application that we're engaged in stabilising and removing technical debt from.  Is it possible to take a hybrid approach - ie, can ASP.NET MVC coexist with webforms within the same web-project?

Are there any gotchas for that?  If it *is* possible, I assume one just has to initialise the routes table, register the ASP.NET MVC handlers, and that's hopefully it...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588027/combine-classic-asp-net-and-asp-net-mvc-within-one-web-application) question.